# Quantities measuring the sparseness of a graph and of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

What are some quantities often used to measure the sparseness of a graph?

1. For example, in a graph, with the number of vertices fixed, the
   smaller the maximum degree is, the more sparse the graph is. With
   the maximum degree fixed, the bigger the number of vertices is, the
   more sparse the graph is.
2. For another example, the more sparse the adjacent matrix is, the
   more sparse the graph is. Then it leads to another question:  [what are some quantities to measure
   the sparseness of a matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254172/what-are-some-measurements-of-the-sparseness-of-a-matrix)

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen 'sparse' and 'dense' for a collection of graphs defined as the number of edges growing as O(n) and O(n^2) respectively - n being the number of nodes.