# What are some measurements of the sparseness of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

What are some measurements of the sparseness of a matrix, which are often used?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The sparsity of a matrix is most commonly defined as the number of nonzero elements divided by the total number of elements.  Say $A$ is $m\times n$; then the sparsity of $A$ is

$$
\frac{\#\{a_{ij}:a_{ij}\neq 0\}}{n\cdot m}
$$

There are many different measures of sparsity in signal processing, however, all of which relate to different notions of compressibility and spectrum.  See [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/survey-10.pdf) article for a thorough discussion of many of them.